# Understanding groovy code in jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm absolutely new to Groovy and Jenskins, please ignore if question sounds noob. Following is a code snippet from a *jenkins* file containing *groovy* code.

```
def boolean hasChanged(String searchText) {
    return sh(
        returnStatus: true,
        script: "git diff --name-only ${GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT} ${GIT_COMMIT} | grep \"${searchText}\""
    ) == 0
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is the above snippet is function/method written in groovy?
2. what does `return sh` do?
3. Per my understanding `script: "git diff --name-only ${GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT} ${GIT_COMMIT} | grep \"${searchText}\""` the output of `grep \"${searchText}\""` is fed into `it diff --name-only ${GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT} ${GIT_COMMIT}`, is the understanding correct?

Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is looks like a Groovy with Jenkins plugins
(`sh`)
Here I Added comments to explain this code.

```
// hasChanged method return boolean value
def boolean hasChanged(String searchText) {
// Insted of 
// def shResult = sh(...); return shResult
// the sh results is returned 
return sh(
        // Preform the sh script and return the script exist code
        returnStatus: true,
        script: "git diff --name-only ${GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT} ${GIT_COMMIT} | grep \"${searchText}\""
    ) == 0 // check script exist code status
}
```

The output of `git diff` is piped to `grep` command that searches for given text in the `git diff output`

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes
2. In this case, the entire Groovy function returns `True` if grep finds `${searchText}` in the output of command `git diff --name-only ${GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT} ${GIT_COMMIT}`, or else `False`.